# Save link to user's PC in Javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, file, download

I have a link return from my controller.

```
public ActionResult ExportGroupSets(parameters){
     ..............
     return(urlLink);
}
```

In my AJAX, I want to download the returned link and save it in user's PC.  How to do that?

BTW, here is an example link return in my controller.

http://localhost/reportrepository/9f43e6fb-6fc1-4527-b6c4-3c26efb80cab.xlsx

I have the following codes in my view page.

```
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("ExportGroupSets", "Home")',
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: JSON.stringify({ ....Parameters....}),
    success: function(url) {
        if (url == "Error: Your connection to this website has timed out. Please login again.") {
            alert(url);
            return;
        }
        -------------------------------------
        codes in saving the file to the users PC.
        -------------------------------------
    },
    error: (function() {
        alert("Error to retrieve selected report");
    })
});
```

Thanks

Rj

Comment: Don't use ajax. Just open that link, and send appropriate download headers.

Comment: how to do that Bergi? thanks

Comment: `window.location.href = 'http://localhost/reportrepository/9f43e6fb-6fc1-4527-b6c4-3c26efb80cab.xlsx';` should suffice

Comment: ah ok got that Bergi.. another question, what do you mean by "send appropriate download headers."?

Comment: https://www.google.de/search?q=http+download+header

Answer (score 0):

You can't save period! JavaScript doesn't let save anything because of security issues. You can use local storage, you can store stuff in string format.